# Selenium IDE: Pass a variable to open URL

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

The below is my Selenium IDE generated XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestCase seleniumIDEVersion="1.0.10" baseURL="http://test.com/">
<selenese>
    <command>open</command>
    <target><![CDATA[/test/contract/?testId=743474]]></target>
    <value><![CDATA[]]></value>
</selenese>
<selenese>
    <command>clickAndWait</command>
    <target><![CDATA[link=View All Test menus]]></target>
    <value><![CDATA[]]></value>
</selenese>
</TestCase>
```

I want to pass a variable here `/test/contract/?testId={variable here}` instead of the number.

Is it possible, please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just code `/test/contract/?testId=${YourVariableName}` and Selenium will substitute it in.  Obviously you'll need to set the variable first, from whatever source you get it from.  The [Selenium reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#parameter-construction-and-variables) has some examples.